# windows xp localtime daylight savings time problem

Tags: c++, windows, time

My XP system with service pack 2 seems to have transitioned to normal non-daylight time BUT the C++ time routines have not.  The Date and Time Properties tool tells me it is now 5:26AM CST BUT localtime() and strftime() think it is 6:26CDT.  I have relinked the app and restarted the system since the daylight switch to no avail.  If I unclick the 'Automatically adjust clock for daylight saving changes'  check box in the Date and Time Properties Time Zone tab, the c++ routines return the CST values.  I admittedly do have an old 2002 XP and Visual Studio.

Comment: hopefully my updated answer helps w/regard to the CRT.

Comment: Not receiving any hints on this problem, I wrote a set of replacement routines for such things as localtime and mktime that convert between time_t - filetime - systemtime and then operate on the systemtime values.  I found that the routines operating on system time work properly on my system.

Answer (score 1):

**Probably the actual answer**

Ah you have a much older version of Win XP. I suspect you do not have a version of Windows XP that was updated to the latest DST dates (they changed in 2007) or somehow its not functioning correctly. I would look into [this hotfix](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=66F1420C-DF2D-400B-A8A9-EF9061A9A3CA&displaylang=en).

[Here's a blog post about the changes for the CRT](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2007/03/08/usa-daylight-savings-time-dst-update.aspx)

Comment: Huh?  I did and that's the problem!  tm_isdst is returned as one even though it is NOT DST.

Comment: @Doug: GetTimeZoneInformation returns the proper bias of 360 minutes for my time zone regardless of the setting of the 'Automatically adjust clock for daylight saving changes' check box in the Date and Time Properties Time Zone tab.

Comment: @Doug: I donwloaded and tried to install the update and got the msg "Update cannot be installed as a newer or same timezone update has already been installed on the system"

Comment: @Doug:  Could this be a run time library problem?  How could I get a copy of Localtim.c?

Comment: Yes it could be a run time library problem... If I recall it may have taken MS a few tries to get this DST change right.